# Kotlin incorrectly inferring type nullability while using RxJava2

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I came onto a quite frustrating problem while trying to program a piece of code responsible for discovering bluetooth devices.

According to Android Studio this piece of code is correct:

```
fun discoverDevices(): Observable<BluetoothDevice> {
    val discovered: HashSet<BluetoothDevice> = HashSet()
    return bluetoothUtil.startDiscovery()
            .flatMapObservable { discoveryStarted ->
                if(discoveryStarted) {
                    RxBroadcastReceiver.create(appContext, IntentFilter().apply {
                        addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)
                        addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED)
                    })
                } else {
                    Observable.error(Throwable("Discovery couldn't be started"))
                }
            }
            .takeUntil { intent ->
                intent.action == BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED
            }
            .map { intent ->
                var bluetoothDevice: BluetoothDevice? = null
                if(intent.action == BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND) {
                    bluetoothDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)
                }
                if(bluetoothDevice != null && !discovered.contains(bluetoothDevice))
                    bluetoothDevice
                else
                    null
            }
}
```

The function declares that it returns `Observable<BluetoothDevice>` even though it is clear that the map function will return `BluetoothDevice?`. Furthermore, it I try to force it to filter null values by appending

```
.filter {
    it != null
}
```

to the end of the chain, the condition `it != null` gets highlighted as "always true" and the return value suddenly becomes `Observable<BluetoothDevice?>`. It's insanely frustrating and I can't seem to find a solution to this weird issue.

Is this a bug with Android Studio or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry for not providing a direct answer, but this kind of messy logic spread across several higher-order functions would become a super-clean and obvious loop if you used Kotlin Coroutines.

Comment: Which are still in the experimental phase, thus I'm not allowed to use it in a production code at my company.

Comment: They have the "experimental" moniker, but they also have JetBrains' 100% commitment to support the experimental API even after release. JetBrains also notes that they are fully production-ready, except that they still reserve the right to change the API in the final version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has a very simple explanation: `null` values are **not** supported in RxJava2.

Using `null` will throw `NullPointerException` at runtime, as explained here: [What's different in 2.0](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What%27s-different-in-2.0).

In your specific case, the IDE highlights the expression as "always true" because RxJava2 operators don't support nullable types, so it will never emit one.

Comment: Well, that was obvious wasn't it. Thanks a lot!